# How to return no timezone date in OData requests?

Tags: .net, sql-server, odata

I have a DateTime property in one of my classes. This property always keeps UTC date. However, when it is serialized to MS SQL it looses the notion of the timezone, so objects created from DB records assume this is a local date. Thus, when I return the date with OData requests it attaches local timezone to the time. For instance, if my UTC date is 2015-01-14 23:00:00, it will be stored in the DB in this format, but via OData I will get 2015-01-14 23:00:00-T07:00.

Is it possible to define the format of the DateTime returned via OData?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to set the timezone for OData?

For simple tutorial, please see: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-01-datetime-support